# DllImport is refusing to find my native .dll. Throws DllNotFoundException

Tags: c#, dll, interop, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a project that references a native dll. I added the .dll to the project and set it to 'copy if newer' so it shows up in the output directory. Still every time I try to call an exported function it throws the not found error.

I did a little research and read that maybe the .dll couldn't find it's dependencies. I used dependency walker to check and the only dependencies listed are are Kernel32.dll and MSCVR80.DLL. Both of those were found on my system.

I used dumpbin.exe and viewed all the exported functions so it does seem to be a properly formatted .dll. I can't figure out why DllImport can't find it.

I also put the DLL in a different directory and added it to my path. That didn't help either. Anyone have any ideas? Anything else I can try?

Comment: Show us please what your P/Invoke declaration(s) look like.

Comment: It would be nice to see the exact error message

Comment: I deleted my answer, but this is similar: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/439376/dllnotfoundexception-multiple-c-and-c-dlls.html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys. I figured it out thanks to Process monitor suggested by dotnettom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Process monitor from Sysinternals tools (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to look at what is accessed. Filter only by the process (otherwise you will get too much data) and see what requests actually failed. This should give you an idea what to look for.

Comment: Using process monitor was extremely enlightening. Turns out my problem was that I was running my code in a unit test and that uses output from a different directory than bin (I'm a unit testing noob so I didn't know). Also apparently my changes to the path environment variable didn't take. Googled it and 64bit windows 7 seems to require a reboot for that. And here I thought .NET just hated me. Thanks.

Comment: Changing path is a really bad idea. Don't do that.